# JMeter Custom Authentication

Tags: authentication, jmeter

We currently employ a non-standard authentication method and provide that in our authorization header for requests.

Due to this, we're at a bind with using a software such as JMeter. I've done some digging but we have no experience in this area.

What would be the best way to move forward with this?

Comment: Get your developer(s) to explain the authentication method step-by-step, and then reproduce it in JMeter step-by-step.

Comment: I wrote the authentication method, it requires custom client side code to intervene between calls. This cannot be reproduced in a sequence of simple api calls. I'm wondering where would we look to implement this for JMeter? Or does it not support this?

Comment: Have you tried JMeter's JSR223 element?

Comment: If all else fails, try the documentation. :) Some helpful links are provided in the tag description https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jmeter/info

Comment: any update on answer ? if one is ok for you , you should accept it and upvote so that it's helpful to other. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several workarounds:

1. You can use a real browser driven by the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/), once you have the authentication context you can extract it and add the header to JMeter's HTTP Request samplers using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/)
2. The custom client code can be implemented in JMeter in the appropriate [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), you can even re-use JavaScript code but be aware that you won't be able to use [Navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) object or anything else connected with the browser.
3. If you don't to load-test the authentication routine itself and want to focus solely on the application you can hard-code a test header which will be accepted by the application and use the aforementioned HTTP Header Manager to supply this token

Answer (score 1):

The approach to do that is to use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with Groovy.

JMeter exposes:

- [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) through **vars**

You'll get a value using:

> vars["varName"]

and store new variable using:

> vars.put("newVarName", newVarThatYouComputeInGroovy);

You can then use the variables as:

> ${newVarName}

If you need to use content from a Request/ Response you can use extractors and export them to variables:

- [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) for JSON
- [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) for HTML
- [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor) for XML
- [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) for any format if none of the above works
- [Regexp Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) for any format if none of the above works